Using embedded Jetty server, openapi.json is not being served after migrating from Jetty 10 to Jetty 12
I'm running a Java application using an embedded Jetty server and JAX-RS. The endpoints are annotated using swagger v3. I have the requirement to serve the openapi.json from the path 'swagger.json' as well so I have added an adapted version of io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources.OpenApiResource to do this. This is all works fine using Jetty 10.
I'm trying to migrate the app from Jetty 10.0.20 to Jetty 12.0.12, I can access the swagger js page but the openapi.json generated from the endpoints is not available, the swagger js page errors with "Failed to load API definition."
Fetch error
Not Found /cva/api/openapi.json
The exact request that is made to the application is a GET request on the path /cva/api/openapi.json which is returning a 404 response.
My problem is that the swagger UI page is no longer working.
Here is the server initialisation code:
// called like this new CvaServer("/cva", getPort()).run()
CvaServer(String contextPath, int port) throws Exception {
        
        server = new Server(port);

        // Set up resource config
        ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
        resourceConfig.packages("io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources",
                "org.gel.cva.server.rest", // This is the package name for my APIs
                "org.gel.cva.server.exceptionmapper",
                "com.jersey.jaxb",
                "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json");
        resourceConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        resourceConfig.register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
        resourceConfig.register(AuthenticatingRequestFilter.class);
        resourceConfig.register(AuditLoggingFilter.class);
        resourceConfig.register(StringNormalisationConverterProvider.class);
        resourceConfig.register(EntityFilteringFeature.class);
        resourceConfig.register(AuthMethodFilter.class);
        EncodingFilter.enableFor(resourceConfig, GZipEncoder.class);

        // Set up ServletContextHandler
        ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
        servletContextHandler.setContextPath(contextPath);

        servletContextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(resourceConfig)), "/api/*");
        servletContextHandler.addEventListener(new CvaContextListener());

        // Set up ResourceHandler
        ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
        resourceHandler.setWelcomeMode(ResourceService.WelcomeMode.REDIRECT);

        servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");
        servletContextHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.html" });

        servletContextHandler.setBaseResource(
                ResourceFactory.of(resourceHandler).newClassLoaderResource("static", true)
        );

        // Set up CrossOriginHandler        
        CrossOriginHandler crossOriginHandler = new CrossOriginHandler();

        crossOriginHandler.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Set.of("*"));
        crossOriginHandler.setAllowedMethods(Set.of("GET","POST","PUT","DELETE","OPTIONS","HEAD"));
        crossOriginHandler.setAllowCredentials(true);
        crossOriginHandler.setAllowedHeaders(Set.of("*"));

        // Set up OpenAPI models
        OpenAPI oas = new OpenAPI();
        oas.setServers(List.of(new io.swagger.v3.oas.models.servers.Server().url("/cva/api")));
        Info info = new Info()
                .title("title")
                .description("")
                .version(CvaConfiguration.CVA_VERSION);

        oas.info(info);

        SwaggerConfiguration oasConfig = new SwaggerConfiguration()
                .openAPI(oas)
                .prettyPrint(true)
                .resourcePackages(Set.of("org.gel.cva.server.rest"));

        // Set up JaxrsOpenApiContextBuilder
        try {
            new JaxrsOpenApiContextBuilder()
                    .application(resourceConfig)
                    .openApiConfiguration(oasConfig)
                    .buildContext(true)
                    .read();
        } catch (OpenApiConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        crossOriginHandler.setHandler(servletContextHandler);
        servletContextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DefaultServlet()), "/*");

        server.setHandler(servletContextHandler);
        
        // Set up Connectors
        ServerConnector serverConnector = new ServerConnector(
                server,
                new HttpConnectionFactory(),
                new HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory(new HttpConfiguration())
        );
        serverConnector.setPort(port);
        server.setConnectors(new ServerConnector[]{serverConnector});
    }

I was expecting that the openapi.json would still be served and that the swagger page wouldn't break

In general any time you are getting an unexpected response from a service, including the exact, request you made that led to that request will be helpful. Setting the request (and error messages) apart from descriptive text with code blocks is also helpful to the folks who may want to answer your question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
